# Co-locate TS typings in dist when using rollup with preserveModules: true and inside of a monorepo

Tags: typescript, rollup, rollupjs

I have the following use-case: A mono-repo utilizing turborepo, typescript, multiple turborepo packages, and each package using rollup with the `preserveModules: true` setting.

I'm using `preserveModules: true` because I'd like to be able to import each component, file, etc independently.

However, if I have `packageA/components/Button.tsx` importing a type from `packageB/types/BaseTypes.ts` get a dist inside of the `packageA` with

```
- dist
  - components
    - Button.js
  - packageA
    - components
      - Button.d.ts
  - packageB
    - BaseTypes.d.ts
```

My hope was that I could end up with something like:

```
- dist
  - components
    - Button.js
    - Button.d.ts
    - BaseTypes.d.ts
```

But that doesn't seem possible. [This](https://github.com/JeffWeim/turborepo-starter) is a github code space with the issue. You'll need to run node 18.0.0, run `yarn build:ui` from the root and inspect the `ui-other` package's dist. In there you'll see the component `@ui-other/components/Button` is importing a type from `import { ButtonSize } from '@ui/Button';`; however the types get moved into a folder of `dist/ui-other/components` but I'd like them to be at `dist/components`

Comment: I've been struggling for 2 days with the configd, changing it from simple `index.js` and `index.d.ts` to separated modules. I was able to automatically put them in their appropriate directoryies I don't know how to manage all of it yet, but if `Button.tsx` imported the the types, it should add them correctly. If not, you'll have to add many objects with `{ input: '...', output: ..., plugins: []` to create a separate outcome for each of them. Like you could add one for `dist/components`, one for `dist/packageA/components` and one for `dist/packageB`, and put all them inside `dist/components`.

Comment: There may be advance techniques for handling multiple chunks and grouping. But so far multiple input/output process is more under control, mainly cause rollup config can conflict with `tsconfig.js` if the `declarationDir` is not a subpath of the output dir of rollup. Which led me to put a different `declarationDir` in each rollup output. I'm gonna take a look at the Repos in 1 hour, and see if I can handle it. I'll let you know.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't find the codespace, maybe it or the repos is private or you removed it.

Comment: Sorry about, that here is the link to the public code space repo: https://github.com/JeffWeim/turborepo-starter

Comment: I found the culprit in why it is choosing `dist/ui-other` instead of just `dist` like the `ui` package. It's because of `rollup-plugin-typescript2`. Inside the codes of `node_modules/rollup-plugin-typescript2/dist/rollup-plugin-typescript2.cjs.js`, in `Line 30325`, add a `console.log('config', parsedConfig);`, you will see the difference in `config.options.pathsBasePath` that has been added only in `ui-other` config, because of `paths` key that you added, with `/ui-other/.` at the end, while the `ui` package doen't have it at all. This is what causing it to put declarations in `ui-other` dir

Comment: Now I'm investigation how to cancel or revert this behavior.

Comment: Wanted to backtrack and see when it removed the `ui` from the output directory for the types, but couldn't. The closest I could get is where the typescript2 plugin, when emitting out and sent it to `node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js`, on function `function getFileEmitOutput(...)` and inside calling program emit `var _a = program.emit(sourceFile, writeFile, ...`. Before this call, filename has `ui` and after that, output filename doesn't have `ui` anymore, but still has `ui-other`. There is many emit functions and no typescript type to follow the code flow, which makes it difficult.

Comment: You could try to move the `dist/ui-other` contents to `dist` and remove `ui-other`, with copy, move and delete plugins, or just normal JS File codes. Don't know if it's gonna be a problem when linking the normal js files to their types.